# Spring MVC Load page automatically

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a quick question about how to use the Spring MVC.
I just started with it and i was used to have pages that always had their data loaded calling some controller that you setted ON THE PAGE.. calling some methods on controllers to load objects at the page at load time.
Is it the same in Spring MVC? Cuz what im seeing so far is that if you want to load a page with data, you always have to use a modelandview object which is loaded by a method that you must call before... and them you return the modelandview object with its destination to the view that you want.

What im trying to know is if there is a way that the page requests some data from the controller before it gets loaded... automatically...

Dont know if im making my self clear... thanks anyway for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in spring mvc, using Controllers, it is always Request->Controller(populates model and chooses view)->Response.
you could use ajax to load data from any resource (even Controllers) or jsp:useBean to explicitly call some business logic or jsp:include to include a certain fragment or a custom jsp tag.

Comment: Thanks man... just wanted to make sure... the thing is a have a list that must be populated every time in a certain page, and many pages redirect to this certain page... what do you think it would be the best approach to achieve this? the jsp:useBean? can i call a method in a controller with that?

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same situation.
check the below link for getting the data from the controller before view(JSP) load.

[how to load the data into index page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391100/how-to-load-the-data-in-index-page-using-spring-mvc)